# не отображается мобильная клавиатура при клике на InputField Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я почитал, по идее клавиатура на телефона должна сама появляться при клике на InputField, у меня не появилась, поэтому я в интернете поискал как ее включить. Смотрел и в оф. документации и видео с ютуба, но клавиатура не появляется.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class open_mobileKeyboard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public username_save name_save_script;
    TouchScreenKeyboard keyboard;


    public void open_keyboard()
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default);
        name_save_script.text = keyboard.text;
        Debug.Log("нажал");
    }
}
```

последнюю строчку добавил, чтобы понять, вызывается ли вообще функция open_mobileKeyboard - вызывается, но клавиатуру не показывает

Answer (score 0):

Я почитал, клавиатура должна сама отображаться без скрипта, но у меня этого не происходит, потому что я не сбилдил свой проект, а просто тестил через Unity Remote 5. После билда проекта в файл, все должно работать